# vagrant check existence of second disk

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I use the below code to create the second disk. When I start the VM first time its creating the disk.  when halt and start the VM again, its trying to create the disk second time and startup failing.  I tried with full path name, still running into same problem.

```
      disk =  "secondDisk.vdi"   

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      unless File.exist?(disk)    
        vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename',disk , '--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 1 * 1024]
      end      
      vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]   
      end
```

Any idea why File.exist check not working?

thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add the absolute path to resolve this problem.

Here is the snippets I used.

```
current_dir    = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))     
disk_perfix = 'secondDisk'
disk_ext ='.vdi'      
disk =  "%s/%s-%02d%s" % [current_dir,disk_perfix, i, disk_ext]
```

Thanks
-SR